# App gets installed/launched for every test annotation in Amazon device farm

Tags: aws-device-farm

Iam not able to test a complete flow in device farm. All the tests run in sequence in local but in device farm, i see for every @test app gets launched from the beginning. I used below annotations in the code.

```
@BeforeSuite - to initialize the driver
@Test - for the test scripts 
@AfterSuite -  iam not quiting the driver
```

Answer (score 0):

AWS Device Farm executes each @Test method individually. Each test method  using a fresh instance of the Appium server and each one of these test methods is executed in a different Java process each time.